# Pipe with ChangeDetectorRef not being refreshed on subscription event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events

I have the following pipe:

```
{{ "value" | translationPipe | async }}


translationPipe {

 constructor(otherService: OtherService, myService: MyService, _ref : ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.myService.myEventEmitter.subscribe(value -> {
         _ref.markForCheck();
    });
 }

 transform(value, args?) {
    // this returns an api call observable
    return this.otherService.doApiCall();
 }

}
```

However when the event emitter outputs an event the value of the pipe is not reobtained.

Comment: Why do you think it will be reevaluated?

Comment: @yurzui  calling _ref.markForCheck would trigger the reavaluation would it not?

Comment: @mangusbrother it marks the *view* for change detection. Pipe's don't have a view.

Comment: where is your transform method?

Comment: @Maximus That's good question :)

Comment: whoops accidentally wrote translate. editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular change detection checks the value and the parameters passed to a pipe for change. If they don't change, calling `markForCheck()` is just a waste of CPU.

A workaround could be to use `pure: false` and return the cached result until `myEventEmitter` emits an event.

Comment: but isn't that slow, Günter? It doesn't seem a good idea to make pipe's transform be called everytime but sometimes you do want to change it's result from a service subscription

Comment: Yes, pure pipes are discouraged. You can introduce artificial pipe parameters that you change when you want the pipe to be executed again like `value | myPipe:counter` where you increment a field `counter` every time you want `myPipe` to re-evaluate.